# How to copy and create test case from JIRA?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

How to copy and create test case from JIRA. Currently I am creating test case as **Create-->Project(XXX)-->Issue Type(Test)** .In this way I have created test case with 8 test steps.Now I would need to create new test case by copying the previous test steps.How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [clone](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/cloning-an-issue-720416353.html) the issue. This is a menu item under the 'More' menu in the issue details screen.

If you can't see More->Clone it is possible your user does not have sufficient privileges to do this operation.